# Play Video on Homepage Only

Tags: pages, html

I've got a video running on my homepage, and I've added the JavaScript below to make sure it plays / loops etc. Which all works fine.

However on the other pages of the site the javascript effectively breaks and affects the functionality of the site. When I look in the console I get a message saying 'cannot ready property 'play' of null.

The code is selecting just the video element on .page-id-36 though, so why is the JS looking for the element on other pages?

the code is:

```
var imagineVideo = document.querySelector('.page-id-36 .et_pb_video_box video');
  imagineVideo.play();
  imagineVideo.loop = true;
  imagineVideo.controls = false;
```

Any help / tips would be great.

Emily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns `null` if no matches are found, so wrap the code that depends on `imagineVideo` in a conditional statement.

```
var imagineVideo = document.querySelector('.page-id-36 .et_pb_video_box video');
if ( imagineVideo ) {
  imagineVideo.play();
  imagineVideo.loop = true;
  imagineVideo.controls = false;
}
```

If you only want this code to be loaded on the homepage, you can put it in a separate file and only enqueue it if the homepage is being viewed. For example, you'd place the code above in `{your-theme}/js/homepage-video.js`. Then you'd enqueue both the main video player script and `homepage-video.js`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_homepage_video_script' );
function wpse_homepage_video_script() {
    if ( is_front_page() ) {

        // Enqueue the main video player.
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'video-player',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/video-player.js',
            array(),
            null,
            true
        );

        // Enqueue the JS that controls the video on the homepage.
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'wpse-homepage-video',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/homepage-video.js',
            array( 'video-player' ),
            null,
            true
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. I never new that about querySelector. Much appreciated.

Comment: Sure! You got it, Emily.